# Search and find the document from HDFS

Tags: solr, hdfs, cloudera

I have loaded the Data(Rich Documents like pdf , doc and txt)  into HDFS using command hadoop fs -put.I should be able to search and find the document . How can i achieve this and I am not bothered of the type of data it holds but just the document only .

Comment: How exactly would you like to search it ? Via command line or via a script ? You can use shell commands to explore the HDFS

Comment: I need to create an application to search it ... I guess if its a command line , I ll try to make the application to run the command ..@Ko2r

Comment: I come across HDFSFindTool . I tried search using it . Its Working fine but ll it be fast enough to handle large amount of data .       Is there any better way to upload data to HDFS instead of hadoop -put command . ?

Comment: I've always used the CLI for these operations but if you want to automate the upload process you can write a bash script, doing the job for you.

Comment: @Ko2r ok ,What is CLI and can is it efficient to use HDFSFindTool for searching from HDFS ?

Comment: CLI is Command Line Interface, it means I'm using a shell (console) for running commands on Hadoop cluster. I've take a look to HDFSFindTool and it's equivalent to the find command in linux systems so you can use it by using CLI according to the documentation. Take a look [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Search/latest/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_hdfsfindtool.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this URL while searching any files in HDFS.

```
 http://localhost:50075/webhdfs/v1/home/HDFSPATH/"+rich_document.pdf+"?op=OPEN")
```

Comment: Please, don't undo improvements to your post. Use 4 spaces for code only. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: 4 spaces! who knew, ty @brasofilo